# Attaching catalog with SQL Authentication credentials attaches it as Read-Only

Tags: sql-server-2005, connection-string, catalog, sql-authentication

As part of our product's installation process, a database is attached to the server.

We use EXEC sp_attach_db in order to attach it to MSSQL.
The problem occures when we try to attach it with "SQL Authentication" connection string - the database is attached to the server as read-only, thus preventing any write access from being performed

This is driving us nuts... it's working just fine with Windows Authentication, and the only difference is the connection string... I tried googling for it but no mention for such a scenario is found.

Any ideas anyone?

It's important to mention that the MDF/LDF **physical** files are not set with "ReadOnly" attribute, so this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you can't attach the database with write permissions and then just make the whole thing read only after the install?

Comment: I don't want the database to be ReadOnly... to the contrary - I want it with write permissions